# Issue with jScrollPane, updating from v1 to v2?

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I have recently bugged Kelvin Luck about an issue I was having with v1 and the scoller not loading due to images appearing after the scroller had initialised: 'scrollpane contains images and needs to reinitialise after the images have loaded'.

After upgrading to v2 the scroller disappeared: http://sugarhut.janddmedia.com/temp.php

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Many Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1):

You need to also update the CSS files related to jScrollPane.

Comment: Great! You can use the tick next to the answer to mark it as the correct answer and close the question ;)